# TinyMCE Toolbar Tooltip slow to appear

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tinymce, tinymce-5

The tooltips for the Toolbar seem to take an extra long time to appear on hover.

I stripped the editor down to a very minimal set of plugins to see if something else was impacting the speed. This is what I was left with:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

export const TinyEditor = ({ editorValue, setEditorValue }) => {
  const plugins = ['image media link hr'];

  const init = {
    min_height: 600,
    width: '100%',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    toolbar1: `link image media hr`,
  };

  return (
    <Editor
      apiKey={tinyKey}
      value={editorValue}
      onEditorChange={(newValue) => {
        setEditorValue(newValue);
      }}
      plugins={plugins}
      init={init}
    />
  );
};
```

I tried with both an open source key, and an essentials key.

It seems to be "acceptable" on Firefox, but both Chrome and Safari produce about the same results.

[Chrome Example](https://www.loom.com/share/eff396fd26d544e9a63ea7f4ab5d286b)

[Firefox Example](https://www.loom.com/share/8d4384d09ff94e2ba31f1a9750e794e1)

This was tested in both a local environment, and on a staging server with the same results.

Any suggestions/recommendations?

Versions:

- @tinymce/tinymce-react: 3.12.6
- react: 16.14.0
- chrome:  93.0.4577.63
- firefox: 92.0
- macOS Big Sur: 11.5.2

Comment: try ask this question in tinymce forum then.

Comment: @windmaomao - there is no dedicated TinyMCE forum so that is not an option. We ask our open source users to post questions here so the entire TinyMCE community can help each other in using our open source editor.

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE uses the `title` attribute to add tooltips to elements.  It is entirely up to the browser as to how they render and when they choose to render these elements (e.g. on hover) on the page.